# Рекурсивная функция для перебора комбинаций массива?

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Как написать рекурсивную функцию для нижеуказанного кода?

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$lim = count($arr);



for($i1 = 0; $i1 < $lim; $i1++) { 
    for($i2 = 0; $i2 < $lim; $i2++) { 
        for($i3 = 0; $i3 < $lim; $i3++) { 
       echo $arr[$i1].$arr[$i2].$arr[$i3].'<br>';
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: похоже на тестовое или учебное задание :) Вам сюда http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: раз так, то предложи вариант

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.е. по сути нужно выполнить полный перебор всех возможных комбинаций элементов массива. Вот так можно:

```
function kuda_mir_katitsa($array, $sequence = '') {
    // Условие остановки рекурсии - когда длина составленной последовательности 
    // равна количеству элементов в нашем массиве
    if (strlen($sequence) === count($array)) {
        echo $sequence . '<br>';
        return;
    }
    // Перебор всех элементов в нашем массиве
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        // К составленной последовательности прицепляем очередной символ и ныряем дальше
        kuda_mir_katitsa($array, $sequence . $item);
    }
}

$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
kuda_mir_katitsa($arr);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, удачи тебе во всех начинаниях

Answer (score 3):

Вот кок-что попробовал реализовать для подбора комбинаций:

```
        /**
         * Возвращает массив комбинаций, учитывая лимит
         * @param array $items - элементы для перебора
         * @param int $limit - лимит элементов в результатах комбинаций
         * @param bool $repeatItems - использовать один элемент несколько раз в одной комбинации
         * @param bool $arrayOrDelimiter - TRUE - если нужно вернуть массивы комбинаций в общем массиве, либо делимитер для элементов в строке
         * @return array
         */
        function getArr_variants($items = array(), $limit = 5, $repeatItems = false, $arrayOrDelimiter = false) {
            static $excludeItems = array();
            $R = array();
            if (!is_array($items)) return array();
            if (!$repeatItems && count($items) < $limit) $limit = count($items);
            ///
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if (isset($excludeItems[$item])) continue;
                if (!$repeatItems) $excludeItems[$item] = '';
                $R[] = $arrayOrDelimiter === true ? array($item) : $item;
                if ($limit > 1) {
                    foreach ($this->getArr_variants($items, $limit - 1, $repeatItems, $arrayOrDelimiter) as $subItem) {
                        $R[] = $arrayOrDelimiter === true ? array_merge(array($item), $subItem) : $item.$arrayOrDelimiter.$subItem;
                    }
                }
                unset($excludeItems[$item]);
            }
            ///
            return $R;
        }
```

Пример:

```
print_r( getArr_variants(array('a','b','c','d')) );
```

Выведет:

```
    Array (
        [0] => a
        [1] => ab
        [2] => abc
        [3] => abcd
        [4] => abd
        [5] => abdc
        [6] => ac
        [7] => acb
        [8] => acbd
        [9] => acd
        [10] => acdb
        [11] => ad
        [12] => adb
        [13] => adbc
        [14] => adc
        [15] => adcb
        [16] => b
        [17] => ba
        [18] => bac
        [19] => bacd
        [20] => bad
        [21] => badc
        [22] => bc
        [23] => bca
        [24] => bcad .... )
```

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in